# How to fix: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: arrays, swift, limit

I am attempting to limit my [String] array to only five values using swifts [.prefix](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689487-prefix)

First I take the original array `items` and splice it using .prefix

```
let testSlice = Array(items.prefix(5))
let newArray = Array(testSlice)
```

Then I validated the array holds only five values with a print line.

```
print("DEV: newArray value: \(newArray)")

if newArray != [] {
    cell.profilePicture.playPortalProfilePic(forImageId: newArray[indexPath.item], { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error requesting profile pic: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    })
} else {
    print("items array was empty, value: \(items)")
}
```

newArray is then passed to a method provided by the SDK I am using to make requests for profilePictures. The newArray holds those values so [indexPath.item] is appropriate here. When this is functioning correctly it creates cells in a collection view dependent on how many values are in the array.

I am currently seeing `Fatal error: Index out of range` when this line attempts to run `cell.profilePicture.playPortalProfilePic(forImageId: newArray[indexPath.item]`

EDIT: Code requested by comments

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }
```

Full method for `cell.profilePicture.playPortalProfilePic(forImageId: newArray[indexPath.item]` line

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        cell.profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = true

        let testSlice = Array(items.prefix(5))
        let newArray = Array(testSlice)

        print("DEV: newArray value: \(newArray)")

        if newArray != [] {
            cell.profilePicture.playPortalProfilePic(forImageId: newArray[indexPath.item], { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error requesting profile pic: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
            }
            )
        } else {
            print("items array was empty, value: \(items)")
        }


        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: show `numberOfitemsAt`

Comment: Can you please show your loop code ? That's where your error probably lies.

Comment: @Priest I apologize if I am incorrect here but are you mentioning for loop code? if so i do not have a for loop in place

Comment: @Sh_Khan can you please clarify? thank you!

Comment: Sh_Khan is asking for you to show your code for `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int`.

Comment: @Sh_Khan, I'm just wondering where you're calling this code from. I'm guessing it's from `cellForRowAtIndex()` ? Also, would be helpful if you provided some sample inputs (if your "items" object)

Comment: @vacawama Thank you! Edited the post and added the method.

Comment: @Priest items is an array of strings, also I edited the question and posted the full method that has the [indexPath.item] line

Comment: Isn't it because newArray count is less than items count? Why don't you return newArray count in numberOfItemsInSection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `items`  as dataSource in `numberOfItemsInSection` while inside `cellForItemAt` use another   `newArray` with less size by `prefix(5)`
  hence the crash , so you should either return the count of `newArrray.count` inside `numberOfItemsInSection` or use `testSlice` alone

Comment: using testSlice alone returns the error `Fatal error: Index out of range` going to try returning newArray.count now

Comment: returning newArray.count worked! Thanks all for the help